# BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_Illuminate_Contracts_Events_Dispatcher::listen() does not exist on this mock object

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

I'm doing some unit testing and want to test so basic stuff. In my test I'mg using `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutEvents`.

When an user registers he or she get's an activation mail. First I used an Observer for that, but came to the conclusion that Laravel doesn't disable the observers when using `WithoutEvents` as writen [here](http://hellofrancesco.com/2015/12/08/a-quickie-dealing-with-observers-and-testing-in-laravel-5-1/) and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/prevent-event-listeners-when-using-model-factories). Then I changed my code to the 'traditional' event and listeners.

EventServiceProvider is still default, except for the `$listen` property:

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\CreateActivation'
    ],
];
```

When I dispatch the event:

`event(new UserCreated($user));`

And an example test (which fails):

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations, WithoutEvents;

    public function testExample()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    }
}
```

The error:

[image: error]

I've no clue why it's is crashing. Because I'm not sure where the problem is caused.

Comment: Try to add `$this->withoutEvents();` in your test case before `$user = factory(User::class)->create();` !!

Comment: I'm already using the `WithoutEvents` trait, which is the equivalent of `$this->withoutEvents()`, but for all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

As said before in the question, the `WithoutEvents` doesn't disable the Observers. As you can see in the error the problem was not with the `UserObserver` or any events, but with the Sluggable package. That package had an observer as well, which was creating the error.

Instead of `$user = factory(User::class)->create();` I created a function in `tests/TestCase.php` which creates an activated user like so:

```
public function activatedUser($attributes = [])
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create($attributes);

    DB::table('activations')->where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();

    return $user;
}
```

So now in the tests you can create activated users: `$user = $this->activatedUser();`